# Spark SQL's Scala API - TimestampType - No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark 2.1 with Scala 2.11 on a Databricks notebook

**What is exactly TimestampType ?**

​We know from ​​[SparkSQL's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types)​ that's the official timestamp type is TimestampType, which is apparently an alias for java.sql.Timestamp :

[TimestampType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType) can be found here in the​ SparkSQL's Scala ​API

**We have a difference when using a schema and the Dataset API**

When parsing `{"time":1469501297,"action":"Open"}` [from the Databricks' Scala Structured Streaming example](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/index.html#structured-streaming-scala)

**Using a Json schema --> OK** (I do prefer using the elegant Dataset API)  :

```
val jsonSchema = new StructType().add("time", TimestampType).add("action", StringType)

val staticInputDF = 
  spark
    .read
    .schema(jsonSchema)
    .json(inputPath)
```

**Using the Dataset API --> KO**:  No Encoder found for TimestampType

Creating the Event class

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
case class Event(action: String, time: TimestampType)
--> defined class Event
```

**Errors when reading the events from DBFS on databricks.**

Note: we don't get the error when using `java.sql.Timestamp` as a type for "time"

```
val path = "/databricks-datasets/structured-streaming/events/"
val events = spark.read.json(path).as[Event]
```

**Error message**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType
- field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType", name: "time")
- root class:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining the schema read method `.schema(jsonSchema)` and the `as[Type]` method containing the type `java.sql.Timestamp` will solve this issue. The idea came to be after reading from the **Structured Streaming** documentation [Creating streaming DataFrames and streaming Datasets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets)

> These examples generate streaming DataFrames that are **untyped**, meaning
>   that the schema of the DataFrame is not checked at compile time, only
>   checked at runtime when the query is submitted. Some operations like
>   map, flatMap, etc. need the type to be known at compile time. To do
>   those, **you can convert these untyped streaming DataFrames to typed
>   streaming Datasets using the same methods as static DataFrame.**

```
val path = "/databricks-datasets/structured-streaming/events/"

val jsonSchema = new StructType().add("time", TimestampType).add("action", StringType)

case class Event(action: String, time: java.sql.Timestamp)

val staticInputDS = 
  spark
    .read
    .schema(jsonSchema)
    .json(path)
    .as[Event]

staticInputDF.printSchema
```

Will output :

```
root
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- action: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 4):

`TimestampType` is not an alias for `java.sql.Timestamp`, but rather a representation of a timestamp type for Spark internal usage. In general you don't want to use `TimestampType` in your code. The idea is that `java.sql.Timestamp` is supported by Spark SQL natively, so you can define you event class as follows:

```
case class Event(action: String, time: java.sql.Timestamp)
```

Internally, Spark will then use `TimestampType` to model the type of a value at runtime, when compiling and optimizing your query, but this is not something you're interested in most of the time.

Comment: With `java.sql.Timestamp` If we use dataset.printSchema we have `time: long`, in the case of the schema we have  `time:timestamp `.
So we still have to cast our time field into a timestamp afterward reading it :/