# How to compare schema of two data frames and write comparison difference result into CSV format

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm comparing schema of two data frame by using  below code

```
val df1= spark.read.option("multiline"true).json("/path")
val df2=spark.read.option("multiline"true).json("/path")

val a= df1.schema.fields  val b= df2.schema.fields

val c=a.map(f => f.dataType).tomap

val d=b.map(f => f.dataType).tomap

val result1=a.filter(f => c.get(f.name) != d.get(f.name)).

val result2=b.filter(f => c.get(f.name) != d.get(f.name)).toList
```

Here I'm getting comparison results of two dataframe

Now I have to write this result into CSV for that I'm converting results1 and results to  list into dataframe is there any another apporoch to write schema comparison into CSV file.

I'm converting result1 and result2 list into dataframe

```
val result1=a.filter(f => c.get(f.name) != d.get(f.name)).toList.toDF()

val result2=b.filter(f => c.get(f.name) != d.get(f.name)).toList.toDF()
```

Getting below error please help me out

[image: error image]

Comment: You are passing something to the function/operation that is not expected, so the exception, e.g. `spark.read.format("avro").load(s3FileNames: _*)` if we pass malformed S3 object path then we get `UnsupportedOperationException`. Observe your code carefully based on this.

Comment: Have a look at this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316974/spark-sqls-scala-api-timestamptype-no-encoder-found-for-org-apache-spark-sq